# Collection with access by both ordinality and key lookup

Tags: java, android, collections

What I am after is a default unordered collection backed by an array or arraylist that allows by-key lookup. Or an associative map that can be traveled ordered by insertion time.

The case is as follows, I have an adapter that moves through the collection via position, and insertion is like a list, but at the same time I would like to change individual elements finding them by key instead of iterating through the whole list.

What I don't want is to have to reimplement a whole Collection from scratch, or intercept the calls for another, because that's bound to error.

Answer (score 3):

[LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) is your best bet.

It works like a HashMap that has a doubly linked list running through its Map.Entry items. You can use the list for iteration and being a HashMap it will give you O(1) lookups.

You can chose insertion order or access order.

Comment: How would I get the entry in position 5 without iterating through the keys?

Comment: I probably need to reformat the question, I'm using an ArrayMap which gives me indexOfKey and keyAt but does not support insertion order.

Comment: So you want Random Access by ordinal as well as O(1) looks for some specified non-ordinal key?

Comment: I know it's a lot to ask, that's why I haven't found anything in the docu by myself.

Comment: There is this implementation of ArrayMap which supports ordering, but it's coupled to other classes http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/ArrayMap.html

Comment: ArrayMap's `get` call is O(n), FWIW.

Comment: I can't think of another way of allowing indexed access except by extending LinkedHashMap to have a backing Map with index as keys. Don't know if such a DS exists in some library. But I'll try to find or whip up an implementation.

Comment: @aa333 that's what I was after, just not implementing it myself because I've been down that road before. See the one I have above by LibGDX. They also have ordered map.

Comment: I linked below `ImmutableMap`, which supports all the operations you mentioned but does not support adding or removing entries.

Comment: It's a mutable list, sadly.

Answer (score 1):

`LinkedHashMap` will give you close to O(1) with insertion order

Answer (score 0):

If you need O(1) indexed lookup as well as O(1) lookup by key, you could do it if you don't need to put new entries into the map, only building the map once (though possibly modifying the entries in the map), with [Guava's `ImmutableMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html), which also preserves insertion order.  Like a normal `Map`, you can do lookups by key, and you can also do `map.values().asList().get(i)`, which gets out an element in constant time.  I don't believe there's anything built into the JDK that does both, however.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @aa333 comment I whipped up my own implementation, it's probably incomplete so suggestions are welcome.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7a93535a3cfb63623a54

It passes this Q&D test cases:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> preMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    preMap.put("subZero", "-1");
    preMap.put("zero", "0");
    IterableLinkedMap<String, String> map = new IterableLinkedMap<String, String>();
    map.putAll(preMap);
    map.put("one", "1");
    map.put("two", "2");
    map.put("three", "3");
    map.put("four", "4");
    map.put("five", "5");
    map.put("six", "6");
    map.remove("three");
    map.put("eight", "8");
    map.put("seven", "7");
    map.remove("one");
    map.put("three", "33");
    map.put("five", "actually five");
    for (int i = 0; i < map.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(map.getPosition(i));
    }
    map.clear();
    System.out.println(map.getPosition(0));
}
```

Results:

```
0
-1
2
4
actually five
6
8
7
33
null
```

Comment: It was a starting point but more things were needed to make it work in O(1) for insertion and lookup of both position and key. The cost is that deletion is O(n), which is a small price to pay IMO.